# google apps script stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

The following html and associated functions stopped working today.

```
<style>

#header {
height:100px;
background:Green;
font-size:300%;
color: Black;
align-content: centre;
}

body {
    width:60%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:10%;
    font-size:16pt;
    font-family:Verdana;
    padding: 100px;

}

#content{

float:centre;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
top:200px;
left:200px;
}

input[type=password]{
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 268px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  /* border-radius: 2px; */
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.animate
{
    transition: all 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}

.action-button
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;  
}

.blue
{
    background-color: #3498DB;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
}

.red
{
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #BD3E31;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #BD3E31;
}

.green
{
    background-color: #82BF56;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}

.yellow
{
    background-color: #F2CF66;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #D1B358;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #D1B358;
}

.action-button:active
{
    transform: translate(0px,5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

</style>





<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

function addClients(clients){
  $('#customer').empty();
  $('#customer').append('<option> ---- Choose a user ----</option>');
  for (var i in clients) {
    $('#customer').append('<option>'+clients[i]+'</option>');
    $('#customer').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }
}

function getval(){
    var selected_value = $( "#customer option:selected" ).text();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onsuccess).validatepass(selected_value);    
}



function onsuccess(retval){
    var enteredpass = $("#psw").val();
    alert(retval);
    if(retval == enteredpass){
      $('#content').hide();
      $('#formselect').show();
    } else
    {
    alert("Wrong Password");
    $("#fmreload").click();
    }
}

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#formselect').hide();  
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addClients).getClients();
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
<div>
<select name="customer" id="customer"  data-native-menu="true" data-role="none">
    <option> ---- Choose a user ----</option>
</select>
</div>


<p><input type="password" name="psw" id="psw"><p>
<p><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getval()" class="action-button animate blue"></p>
<?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=index'> <input type='button' name='formreload' id="fmreload" style="display:none;"></a>

</div>

<div id='formselect'>

<a href='https://script.google.com/a/macros/greenleaf-uae.com/s/AKfycbz_kIsYn4A-3FjeWmQihzFl7rfT73AN1oWu15xDoHHgWGnY29k/exec?page=formselect'>User Forms</a>

</div>
</body>
```

The functions called on GAS side are

```
function validatepass(selected_value){
 var usrpass ="this was called";
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(empmaster);
 var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
 var data = sheet.getRange(3, 3, sheet.getLastRow(),6).getValues();// read all data in the sheet
 for(var n=0;n<data.length;++n){
   var row = data[n][0];
   if(row.toString().match(selected_value) == selected_value){ 
     usrpass = data[n][4];
     PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('curruser', selected_value);
     PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('currsup', data[n][1]);
     PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('issup', data[n][5]);
     PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('usermail', data[n][2]);
     PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('supmail', data[n][3]);  
   };
 } 

  return usrpass;
}
```

This script was working fine till this morning.

The password is justpass and it should match the returned value. However, when I check in firefox, the returned value is

```
)]}'

[["op.exec",[0,"\"justpass\""]
]
]
```

this is exactly the password that I enter.

Regards,
Arjun

Comment: What is the issue? are yo getting an error? if so, what error?